# Two problems with this java code, one fatal one not as fatal what are they?

Tags: java, xml, csv

Here is my code. This was a program I made for an interview, I was told the code had one fatal flaw, and one smaller problem. I could not find either. What is wrong with the program? I've tested it and it seems to work fine. I know the fileExists() method is kind of bad and need to do more checks... But other than that I am not sure what else could be wrong...

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

//I chose to use this library since it offers a solution to performing operations on CSV files, better than one I can provide from scratch.
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader; 


public class csv2xml {

    //Main program loop 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFilename;
        String xmlFilename;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data; //Raw unformatted data
        boolean exists;
        String xml;                     //Formated XML data
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter file path: ");
            csvFilename = getUserInput();   //Gets filename from user
            exists = fileExists(csvFilename);
            if(exists){ //Checks to see if file exists
                data = readFile(csvFilename);       //Reads in content from CSV file
                xml = toXML(data);
                xmlFilename = csvFilename.split("\\.")[0]+".xml"; //Gets part of the filename before the first .
                writeToFile(xml,xmlFilename);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid file name, use full file path.");
        }while(!exists);
    }

    //Reads a line of input from the user
    //Returns: String
    public static String getUserInput(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        return input;
    }

    //Checks to see if the file exists
    //Arguments: String (name of file)
    //Returns Boolean, true if file exists, false if it does not exist.
    public static boolean fileExists(String filename){
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File exists");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Reads content of CSV file and returns all data in a 2D array list
    //Arguments: String (file name)
    //Returns: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> (A 2D arraylist containing the data from the csv file in a table format)
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFile(String filename){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> currentRow;
        CSVReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String [] nextLine = null; // nextLine[] is an array of values in the current line

        try {
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                currentRow = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String s: nextLine){ //Puts data into a row in an arraylist
                    currentRow.add(s);
                }
                data.add(currentRow);   //Adds row into arraylist
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    //Inserts xml tags between the data segments,rows and columns
    //Arguments: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> (csv data)
    //Returns: String (data with xml tags)
    public static String toXML(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data){
        String xml = "<?xml version= \"1.0\"?>";
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            xml += "\n<row id=\""+i+"\">\n";
            for(int z = 0; z < data.get(i).size(); z++){
                xml += "<column id=\""+z+"\">\n";
                xml += "\t<data>";
                xml += data.get(i).get(z);
                xml += "</data>";
                xml += "\n</column>\n";
            }
            xml += "</row>";
        }
        return xml;
    }

    //Writes data in the filename specified
    //Arguments: String (data to write), String (filename to write data to)
    public static void writeToFile(String data,String filename){
        try {

            String fn = filename;

            File file = new File(filename);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File already exists, overwrite?(y/n):");
                if(getUserInput().toLowerCase().equals("n")){
                    do{
                        System.out.println("Enter new file name:");
                        filename = getUserInput()+".xml";
                        file = new File(filename);
                    }while(!isValidName(filename));
                }
            }
            else{
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(data);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Check files name to make sure it is valid (found in MSDN Documentation)
    //Arguments: String (filename)
    //Returns: Boolean (true if filename is valid false if invalid)
    public static boolean isValidName(String text)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "# Match a valid Windows filename (unspecified file system).          \n" +
            "^                                # Anchor to start of string.        \n" +
            "(?!                              # Assert filename is not: CON, PRN, \n" +
            "  (?:                            # AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, \n" +
            "    CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|             # COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9,     \n" +
            "    COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9]            # LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5,     \n" +
            "  )                              # LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9...     \n" +
            "  (?:\\.[^.]*)?                  # followed by optional extension    \n" +
            "  $                              # and end of string                 \n" +
            ")                                # End negative lookahead assertion. \n" +
            "[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*\\x00-\\x1F]*     # Zero or more valid filename chars.\n" +
            "[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*\\x00-\\x1F\\ .]  # Last char is not a space or dot.  \n" +
            "$                                # Anchor to end of string.            ", 
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        boolean isMatch = matcher.matches();
        return isMatch;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ask the interviewers. Who knows what they consider flaws.

Comment: You don't appear to close your CSV reader, never used the lib so not sure if its a necessity but most IO requires closing of streams when finished with.

Comment: Also the  `xmlFilename = csvFilename.split("\\.")[0]+".xml"` is a bit dangerous. For example if you have `file.1.csv` and `file.2.csv` you will create only one xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I guess :

```
CSVReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String [] nextLine = null; // nextLine[] is an array of values in the current line

    try {
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            currentRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String s: nextLine){ //Puts data into a row in an arraylist
                currentRow.add(s);
            }
            data.add(currentRow);   //Adds row into arraylist
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So what happens if you do not initialize CSVreader ? The next block will throw a NullPointer Exception. You are not catching that one.

Also you are reading manually line by line when you can you simply use the library function.